# Angular TypeScript cannot read properties of undefined error

Tags: angular, typescript, properties, undefined

I have following interface:

```
export interface IQuest {
Id: number,
lat: number,
lon: number,
Question:string,
Answer:boolean,
IsDone:boolean,
Correct:boolean,
Range:number}
```

And following component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

currentUserLatitude=49.8121157;
currentUserLongitude=19.041796;
constructor(private http:HttpClient){};

data:IQuest[]|any=[];

ClosestLocation:IQuest|any;

ngOnInit(){
this.getClosestQuest();
}

getClosestQuest(){   
let url = "http://127.0.0.1:5153/api/GetClosest? 
cuLon="+this.currentUserLongitude+"&cuLat="+this.currentUserLatitude;
console.log("getClosestQuest() -nowWorking");
this.http.get(url).subscribe(data=>{
  console.warn(data);
  console.log(data);
  
  this.ClosestLocation=data;
});
```

[image: Result of console.warn]

But when i try to get values of ClosestLocation using any function, for example:

```
displayQuestion(){
console.warn("range: "+this.ClosestLocation.Range);
}
```

I get error in console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Range')
at AppComponent.displayQuestion (app.component.ts:81:61)
at AppComponent.ngAfterViewInit (app.component.ts:31:10)
at callHook (core.mjs:2488:22)
at callHooks (core.mjs:2457:17)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2408:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:10490:21)
at detectChangesInternal (core.mjs:11624:9)
at RootViewRef.detectChanges (core.mjs:12115:9)
at ApplicationRef.tick (core.mjs:25402:22)
at ApplicationRef._loadComponent (core.mjs:25440:14)
```

How can I assign value to ClosestLocation so that I can access it later?
When I changed API call to return object type of

```
ClosestLocation:IQuest[]|any;
```

I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: When you are calling the method "displayQuestion"? Ideally it should be inside of your subscription.

Comment: I called it after getClosestQuest(), but if i call it inside subscription I'm getting "range: undefined"

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong casing. JavaScript is case sensitive

Comment: Where @AluanHaddad?

Comment: In your console log, showing the object structure, the property names are lowercase. However, you may have other problems as well I haven't looked too closely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
console.warn("range: "+this.ClosestLocation?.range);
```

This also could be due to `ClosestLocation` being `undefined`.